calculate highest occurring factor level across multiple columns of grouped data in R
I have a dataframe:
df = data.frame(temperature = c(rep("1", 3), rep("2", 5), rep("3", 2)), var1 = c(rep("apple", 5), rep("banana", 5)), var2 = c(rep("aardvark", 2), rep("baboon", 3), NA, rep("coyote", 4)), var3 = c(NA,rep("cherry", 6), rep("dodo", 3)))

and want to group by temperature and find the most common factor level across all columns for each temperature and give the count of value as below:



temperature
most common
occurrences




1
apple
3


2
dodo
4


3
banana
2



I've tried to modify solutions from R: Find the most frequent factor level within each group separately for each column and had a play with summarise and across but not having any luck.
Any help greatly appreciated

One way is to pivot.
Without ties:
pivot_longer(df, -temperature) |>
   filter(!is.na(value)) |>
   group_by(temperature) |>
   count(value) |>
   slice_max(n, with_ties = FALSE)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   temperature [3]
  temperature value      n
  <chr>       <chr>  <int>
1 1           apple      3
2 2           cherry     4
3 3           banana     2

With ties:
pivot_longer(df, -temperature) |>
  filter(!is.na(value)) |>
  group_by(temperature) |>
  count(value) |>
  slice_max(n, with_ties = TRUE)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   temperature [3]
  temperature value      n
  <chr>       <chr>  <int>
1 1           apple      3
2 1           cherry     3
3 2           cherry     4
4 3           banana     2
5 3           coyote     2
6 3           dodo       2


Thank you, didn't seem to work with my dataset - all values in value column were NA. Not sure if that's because I have a lot of NA values in the dataset. Have updated the example df to contain NAs

Even after your edit, the answer remains the same. Try on your real data with the addition of filter (see edit).

That's done it, thanks:)

foo_mode <- function(x) {
  freq <- table(x)
  data.frame(most_common = names(freq)[which.max(freq)], occurences = max(freq))
}
split(df[paste0("var", 1:3)], df$temperature) |>
  lapply(\(x) foo_mode(unlist(x))) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "temperature")

#   temperature most_common occurences
# 1           1       apple          3
# 2           2      cherry          4
# 3           3      banana          2


A base R solution
do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
        split(df, ~temperature),
        \(x) {
            cbind(
                temperature = x[[1]][1],
                setNames(
                    rev(stack(tail(sort(table(t(x[-1]))), 1))),
                    c("most_common", "count")
                )
            )
        }
    )
)

gives
  temperature most_common count
1           1       apple     3
2           2      cherry     4
3           3        dodo     2
>

